# trying to install .bash_profile on terminal

Tags: bash, macos, flutter

I'm having a very hard time installing flutter when I opened my terminal and tried to open the bash profile and I entered open -e .bash_profile on the therminal,  I get error stating that my .bash_profile does not exit please see below, can someone help me I been researching and trying to figured what's wrong and no one seems to have an answer.

```
Last login: Sun Apr 28 00:06:05 on console

Veasnas-MacBook-Pro:~ veasnamam$ open -e .bash_profile

The file /Users/veasnamam/.bash_profile does not exist.

Veasnas-MacBook-Pro:~ veasnamam$
```

Comment: How do I install flutter on the empty or blank .bash_profile?

Answer (score 0):

You easily can create a new, empty `.bash_profile` by doing a `touch ~/.bash_profile`.

Afterwards run `open -e .bash_profile` again.

In my case (MacBook Pro too) the file `.bash_profile` exists, but is empty (I'm using ZSH anyhow) so don't worry if yours does not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much it works! wow thanks again, I'm taking a dart/flutter course on Udemy, I asked the instructor about this issues and he seems to don't know about it, you should teach on Udemy.